# git clean directories in untracked files

Tags: git, git-status, git-clean

How can I remove directories from untracked files that aren't appearing in `git clean -n`? Here are my steps:

`git status`

...gives me:

```
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

css/
../../../../../../../../site-testing/lru-cache/
```

I get no results from `git clean -n` (or `git clean --dry-run`).

How can I remove these directories from appearing in untracked files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add them to a .gitignore file

http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 2):

if you want to delete all the files, which are not controlled by git, use

```
git clean -d -f -x
```

if you want to ignore them -- use `.gitignore` file as @tom.alexander suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
git clean -xdf
```

It restores your directory (and sub-directories) to pristine condition.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `git clean` operates recursively from the current working directory. Try moving to a parent directory of your working copy and invoking it from there:

```
cd ../../../../../../../../
git clean -n
```